# tnameserv: control Location Forward

Tags: java, corba

Is there a way to control the IP used in the Location Forward mechanism of the "tnameserv", which is delivered with the Java JDK?

For some reason the choice of IP seems random, which does not work when you only allow communication through the original IP (not the IP in the location forward).

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution consists of adding the -ORBServerHost property, which is a property the tool passes to the ORB it uses.